# How to replace original content:" - " inside a class='btn'>" - "< after the element has been :hover:after

Tags: html, css

Output on ':hover'  is always

"1IPSUM"

And if i decide to add a ':before' element with 'content:"1"' it just adds a 1 making the output before hover "11"

The output i am looking for is:

on 'hover' "IPSUM"

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Zxdfvv/u9xgoks3/

```css
.btn:hover:after {
  padding-bottom: 200px;
  content:"IPSUM";
}
```

```html
<div class='btn'>1</div>
```

Comment: Please use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon has `<>`) instead of what you're doing now. It has boxes for HTML and CSS and a Run code snippet button so we can see what it does. Your question does not really make sense though. It would be best if you could say what you want to happen when.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the `content:` for the pseudo-element, not for the element itself. That's why when you add content to `::before` it shows up *before* the text of the element, and then why in turn it shows after if you use `::after`.

What you could do is set the initial text using pseudo-elements, too. So you could do:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #006400;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

main {
  padding: 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1em;
}

.btn {
  border: 3px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
  background-color: #ffd700;
  color: black;
  font-family: monospace;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
}

.btn::after {
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn--empty::after {
  content: "";
}

.btn--pseudo::after {
  content: "lorem";
}
.btn:hover::after {
  content: "ipsum";
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <main>
  
    <a class="btn btn--empty" href="#"></a>

    <a class="btn btn--pseudo" href="#"></a>

  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank u, EmSixTeen! Im away at school so I am unable to log into my account. Will Pseudo elements work the same on different browsers?

Comment: They *should* work the same on all browsers, yes. You can check [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=pseudo-elements) to check for browser support, but there's no guarantee that each will behave identically.